# Windows Phone CollectionViewSort not showing anything

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, collectionviewsource

I am trying to develop a page in a WP8 app which has a search box at the top and a list of items that match the search below, updating as the search box updates. Pretty straightforward, right? Except I can't get it to work.

After perusing StackOverflow and the interwebz, the recommended solution seems to be to use `CollectionViewSource`. Well, I'm trying to use it and no items show up. As soon as I switch to the `ObservableCollection` containing my items in XAML, everything shows up fine.

My data is loaded asynchronously from a DB.

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Grid.Row="0" Hint="search query" ActionIcon="/Assets/Search.png" Text="{Binding SearchQuery, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <themes:TextBoxUpdateOnTextChangedBehavior />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </toolkit:PhoneTextBox>
    <phone:LongListSelector Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" />
    <!-- I have also tried binding to SearchResults.View with no success -->
</Grid>
```

**View Model**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel> _allItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel>();

    public CollectionViewSource SearchResults { get; private set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        SearchResults = new CollectionViewSource { Source = _allItems };
        _allItems.CollectionChanged += (_, __) => SearchResults.View.Refresh();

        LoadAllItemsAsync();
    }

    private async void LoadAllItemsAsync()
    {
        IList<MyItemModel> models = await LoadMyModels();
        _allItems.AddRange(models.Select(model => new MyItemViewModel(model)));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I haven't even attempted to write filtering code yet. Shouldn't the code above basically show a LongListSelector with all the items I have loaded? If I change the `SearchResults` type to `ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel>` and have the getter return `_allItems`, my page shows the expected items. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `LongListSelector` control requires that its `ItemsSource` implements `IList`, which CollectionViewSource doesn't do. This means you can't bind a `CollectionViewSource` to a `LongListSelector` out of the box. You can see this by trying to set it in the code-behind file like this:

```
myLongListSelector.ItemsSource = myCollectionViewSource.View;
```

Which gives an error saying it can't convert the view to an `IList`.

I know atleast two solutions to this, one is to write a wrapper class around CollectionViewSource which does implement IList and then bind to that. Another question gives an example of this (I haven't tried it thought): [LongListSelector grouping using CollectionView in Windows Phone 7 or Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251274/longlistselector-grouping-using-collectionview-in-windows-phone-7-or-windows-pho)

Another method is to not use `CollectionViewSource` and instead using `System.Linq` for sorting like suggested in this question: [How to Sort a LongListSelector in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815570/how-to-sort-a-longlistselector-in-windows-phone/18815761?noredirect=1#18815761)

Comment: Huh. I had no idea about that. Let me try one of those other fixes. Or just use an ItemsControl.